# How to pass $_GET variable to a .load php file

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a JavaScript function that loads my `main-section.php`  inside  `profile.php`

```
    $(".profile-click").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $id = $(this).attr("id");
        switch($id){strong text
            case "main-click":
            $("#information-container").load("profile/main-section.php");
            break;
        }
    });
```

I want to display some text when a user has an error in `main-section.php`, so naturally I'll try to send an `$_GET['']` variable but it does not display on my `main-section.php`

I try to send it via `window.location.href='../profile.php?error=short_username';` though this doesn't work, sending it to `main-section.php?error=short_username` sends it to the wrong page

Comment: What's your issue?  `$("#information-container").load("profile/main-section.php?error=short_username");` will work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send your data like this:

```
$("#information-container").load("profile/main-section.php?variable=my_data&another_variable=another_value");
```

By appending your variables into the URL.

Then you can use on your `main-section.php`

```
echo $_GET['variable']; // my_data
echo $_GET['another_variable'] // another value
```

Also you might want to use `isset` to make sure the variables are defined before use them .

Like:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['variable' ) ) {
   echo $_GET['variable'];
}
```